# HDP 2.5: Spark History Server UI won't show incomplete applications

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I set-up a new Hadoop Cluster with `Hortonworks Data Platform 2.5`. In the "old" cluster (installed `HDP 2.4`) I was able to see the information about running Spark jobs via the History Server UI by clicking the link `show incomplete applications`:

[image]

Within the new installation this link opens the page, but it always sais `No incomplete applications found!` (when there's still an application running).

I just saw, that the `YARN ResourceManager UI` shows two different kind of links in the "Tracking UI" column, dependent on the status of the Spark application:

[image]

- application running: Application Master

  - this link opens http://master_url:8088/proxy/application_1480327991583_0010/
- application finished: History

  - this link opens http://master_url:18080/history/application_1480327991583_0009/jobs/

Via the YARN RM link I can see the running Spark app infos, but why can't I access them via Spark History Server UI? Was there somethings changed from HDP 2.4 to 2.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it was a network problem: Some of the cluster hosts (Spark slaves) couldn't reach each other due to a incorrect switch configuration. Found it out, as I tried to ping each host from each other.

Since all hosts can ping each other hosts the problem is gone and I can see active and finished jobs in my Spark History server UI again!

I didn't noticed the problem, because the ambari-agents worked on each host, and the ambari-server was also reachable from each cluster host! However, since ALL hosts can reach each other the problem is solved!